# Installing Solaris 10 on sunT5220 - ZFS/UFS raid 10?

Tags: solaris, raid10

I am in a bit of a time crunch, and need to get two T5220's built. We were very happy to see two boxes in our aged inventory which had 8 HDD's each, but didn't think to check if they were running hardware RAID or not. Turns out that they aren't. When we install, we are given the option to use UFS or ZFS, but when we select a place to install we're only given the option of installing on one single disk. Is it possible to create a software raid 10 across all of the disks and install the OS on that?

Sorry if any lingo is wrong, I'm not really a Sun guy and our guru is out of town right now. Any help would be really appreciated!

Note: Most of the guides I've found on google entail installing the OS on a single disk, and then creating a separate RAID 10 on other disks. We would actually like the OS to reside on the RAID 10. Hope that clarifies things.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'll read this, but for the benefit of future readers...

You can install on one UFS disk and then set up mirrors to other disks after it's done. OR you can make a root ZFS pool (with two or more more disks in it) and install there.

Comment: You can also easily add a disk for mirroring to a ZFS single disk root. Unless you know for certain that ZFS can't work for you, you should be using ZFS for any Solaris 10 (or later) system.

Comment: Also note that the zfs root pool can only be a mirror, not raidz or striped mirrors (i.e., RAID 10).